# WHERE condition and Limit clause will increase the performance or not?

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-testing

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
`job_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`job_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`job_desc` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`job_date` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Let's assume this table contains 600,000 entries

**Question 1: Which one is good to use and possible to increase the query performence?**

```
SELECT job_name FROM jobs WHERE job_id = 10005

Vs

SELECT job_name FROM jobs WHERE job_id = 10005 LIMIT 1
```

**Question 2: What is the drawback if I use this?**

```
SELECT job_name FROM jobs WHERE job_id = 10005 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: first all the records are selected using where clause and then they are limited by using limit and as in your case there will always be only one record so using limit is unnecessary

Comment: What is the drawback if I use limit clause this?

Comment: i don't think there is any drawback but here it is just unnecessary to use limit on record which is one from start to end

Comment: Only drawback I can see is that it has to do a tiny bit more processing the parse the query, and then possibly a tiny bit more to limit the result. But the extra time would be so small as to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, LIMIT helps in paginating data. So, There would definitely be performance differences when the query contains/not contains LIMIT clause.

'LIMIT n' constraints the number of rows returned. The below would return only first 20 rows.

```
SELECT employee FROM employees WHERE deparment_id = 1 LIMIT 20
```

But 'LIMIT n,p' paginates the matching records. for example, the below would return the 11th to 16th records that match the WHERE condition.

```
SELECT employee FROM employees WHERE deparment_id = 1 LIMIT 10,5
```

So, in cases where the number of rows returned is big, LIMIT would improve performance. However, this might vary depending on the number of rows matching and the pagination range.

Comment: Dude job_id is a primary key then how can it return 20 or 5 rows .If you want to explain limit then take some other example

Comment: Thanks Ankit! modified the query part :)